# Azure Functions BlobTrigger blobPath nested configuration binding

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have this BlobTrigger method. I would like the configuration name `ContainerName` to be moved to a nested path.

For example :

`public void DoStuff([BlobTrigger("%ContainerName%/{blobName}")] string blobName)`

would be changing to something like :

`public void DoStuff([BlobTrigger("%ParentConfiguration.ContainerName%/{blobName}")] string blobName)`

Other components of Azure, that hold configuration, such as AppServices or KeyVaults (and even function apps themselves!) have a way to declare nested configuration, but the `BlobPath` property of the `BlobTriggerAttribute` class does not seem to support such nesting for binding purposes.

Why is that? Is it just because this has never been requested before? Is it because there is something I'm doing wrong, or missing from the azure webjobs sdk documentation?

Answer (score 0):

After playing around a little with the configuration binding engine, I finally stumbled across the answer, which ended up to be quite simple, and in fact, exactly the same as how the AppService configuration must be declared in Azure when the configuration keys are nested.

The answer is :

`public void DoStuff([BlobTrigger("%ParentConfiguration:ContainerName%/{blobName}")] string blobName)`

(Notice the column character, instead of the '.' character)